# Update field based on a ManyToManyField in Django model when saving

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a model Sale defined as follows:

```
from django.db import models
class Sale(models.Model):
    sale_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    lead_seller = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related name = "lead")
    sellers = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related name = "sellers")
    lead_share = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 4, decimal_places = 3, null = True, blank = True)
    sellers_share = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 4, decimal_places = 3, null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sale_name
```

And I have created a front-end form where people can register new sales. On saving, I want to compute the "commission" to each seller. E.g. the leads get 10% and other sellers get 5%. This rate is constant, and thus commission is lower when more sellers are involved in a single sale. I have tried the following:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
@receiver(post_save, sender=Sale, dispatch_uid="update_shares")
def update_shares(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    no_leads = Sale.lead_seller.through.objects.filter(sale_id = instance.id).count()
    no_sellers = Sale.sellers.through.objects.filter(sale_id = instance.id).count()
    instance.lead_share = 0.1/no_leads
    instance.sellers_share = 0.05/no_sellers
```

However it seems the database query gives 0: the error I get when trying to create a new entry is "Zero Division Error /". Any suggestions on how I can get the number of leads/sellers in a smooth fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `instance` is a `Sale` object you can just do:

```
no_leads = instance.lead_seller.count()
no_sellers = instance.sellers.count()
```

Also note that maybe you want to update the calculation als when updating the many-to-many relations, but when doing this `post_save` is not called, you would need [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed).

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Sale.lead_seller.through)
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Sale.sellers.through)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Sale, dispatch_uid="update_shares")
def update_shares(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # do your stuff....
```

Comment: This still gives 0, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible the signal handler gets called when the `Sale` model is updated, not when the related objects are added? See my updated answer, your probably need to listen for `m2m_changed`...